# Select All Records From One Table, Specific Records From Another

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I have three tables.

```
Table1(Table1Id, Field1, Field2)
Table2(Table2Id, Table1Id, AuditDate, Field1, Field2)
Table3(Table3Id, Table1Id, AuditDate, Field1, Field2)
```

What I'd like to do with this is to select all records and fields in Table1, look into Table2 and Table3 for a matching Table1Id and select the record with the latest AuditDate from Table3. I feel I need to make a query something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Table1Id, Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2,
               Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2,
               Table3.Field1, Table3.Field2
FROM (Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Table1Id = Table2.Table2Id)
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table1.Table1Id = Table3.Table3Id
WHERE Table3.AuditDate =
    (SELECT MAX(AuditDate) FROM Table3
     WHERE Table1.Table1Id = Table3.Table3Id)
```

This semi works. For example, if there aren't any records in Table3 that relate back to Table1, nothing will come back. I need to ensure that a record for every record in Table1 is created.

Comment: I've flagged this question to be removed as it isn't explained properly and I don't want to edit it after answers have already been posted. I've explained it properly in another question.

Answer (score 1):

It should be a query like this:

```
SELECT t1.field1..t1.fieldN, t2.field1 ... t2.fieldN, t3.field1 ... t3.fieldN
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.id=t3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,

```
select Table1Id,field1,field2 from Table1,Table2,Table3 
    where 
        Table1.Table1Id=Table2.Table2Id and 
        Table1.Table1Id=Table3.Table2Id and 
        Table2.AuditDate=Table3.AuditDate 
    group by Table1Id,field1,field2 
    having Table2.AuditDate = (
        Select max(AuditDate) from Table1,Table2,Table3 
            where  
                Table1.Table1Id=Table2.Table2Id and 
                Table1.Table1Id=Table3.Table2Id and  
                Table2.AuditDate=Table3.AuditDate 
            group by Table2.AuditDate
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the results from your original query, plus the records from Table1 for which no corresponding record is found in Table3 (or Table2). This can be obtained by replacing your `INNER JOIN`s with `LEFT JOIN`s, and converting the `WHILE` clause to an `ON` clause. You then get this query, that will return records from Table1 even if no corresponding records are found in the other tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.Table1Id, Table1.Field1, Table1.Field2,
               Table2.Field1, Table2.Field2,
               Table3.Field1, Table3.Field2
FROM (Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.Table1Id = Table2.Table2Id)
LEFT JOIN Table3
ON Table1.Table1Id = Table3.Table3Id
AND Table3.AuditDate =
    (SELECT MAX(AuditDate) FROM Table3
     WHERE Table1.Table1Id = Table3.Table3Id)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS T1
    JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.Table1Id = T2.Table1Id 
    JOIN Table3 AS T3 ON T1.Table1Id = T3.Table1Id 
    GROUP BY T2.AuditDate
```